# Why can't I smash rocks with Rock Smash?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

Hey guys I have Pokemon Ruby on GBA and I have a problem. I have obtained rock smash and taught it to one of my Pokemon, but I still can't smash the rocks in the tunnel at Slateport. What might be the issue?

Comment: Have you beaten the Mauville City Gym yet?

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't beaten Wattson of the Mauville City Gym yet, therein lies the problem. [Hidden Machines](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/HM) tend to require that you beat a specific gym before the moves can be used outside of battle, often to get at hidden item balls, or to clear a path forward. It is primarily used in order to keep the player from doing things out of sequence; you cannot proceed to the next town until you have found the HM required to take the path, and beaten the gym leader to unlock it as a field move.